# vector.push_back() method call is not working in c++

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault, coredump

I am new to c++, i am trying to read first four words of each line written in a file and assign to it a object of my class viz Detected_Object. I want to store these objects into vector. When i try to push_back object of my class into segmentation fault(Core Dumped) error comes.

Other methods of vector like size, max_size() and capacity() are working fine on vector but on push_back() it is giving error.

I have tried following workarounds that i have found so far:
1. Tried using vector of pointers to object instead object itself.
2. Tried to initialize vector with new keyword and then use it.
3. Resized vector to hold 10 elements.
but none of the above worked, i am not getting any clue of what i am doing wrong. The code base is as follow:

```
vector<Detected_Object*> objects;
ifstream fp;
string filename="../data/area_info/"+to_string(i)+".jpg.info";
fp.open(filename);

int left,right,top,bottom;
string line;
//end tracking if list of detected object is null
if(fp && fp.peek() == EOF){
    return;
}else{
    //read all detected objects from single frame   
    while (getline(fp, line)) {
        int counter=0;
        istringstream buf(line);
        istream_iterator<std::string> beg(buf), end;

        std::vector<std::string> tokens(beg, end); // done!
        for(string& s: tokens){
            std::cout << '"' << s << '"' << '\n';
            if(counter==0){
                left=stoi(s);
            }else if(counter == 1){
                right =stoi(s);
            }else if(counter == 2){
                top = stoi(s);
            }else if(counter == 3){
                bottom = stoi(s);      
                counter=0;
                cout<<"value of left coordinate: "<<left<<" right: "<<right<<" top: "
                <<top<<" bottom: "<<bottom<<endl;
                break;                                         
            }
            counter++;
        }

        Detected_Object obj(left,right,top,bottom);
        cout<<"max sizeof  vector of detected objects ";
        cout<<objects.max_size();
        //cout<<"detected object left: "<<obj.left<<"right: "<<right<<"top: "<<obj.top<<"bottom: "<<obj.bottom;
        objects.push_back(&obj);
    }

}
```

Edit:

The following code also does not work:

```
vector<Detected_Object> objects = vector<Detected_Object>();
Detected_Object obj;
ifstream fp;
string filename="../data/area_info/"+to_string(i)+".jpg.info";
fp.open(filename);

int left,right,top,bottom;
string line;
//end tracking if list of detected object is null
if(fp && fp.peek() == EOF){
    return;
}else{
    //read all detected objects from single frame       

    while (getline(fp, line)) {
        int counter=0;
        istringstream buf(line);
        istream_iterator<std::string> beg(buf), end;

        std::vector<std::string> tokens(beg, end); // done!
        for(string& s: tokens){
            std::cout << '"' << s << '"' << '\n';
            if(counter==0){
                left=stoi(s);
            }else if(counter == 1){
                right =stoi(s);
            }else if(counter == 2){
                top = stoi(s);
            }else if(counter == 3){
                bottom = stoi(s);      
                counter=0;
                cout<<"value of left coordinate: "<<left<<" right: "<<right<<" top: "
                <<top<<" bottom: "<<bottom<<endl;
                break;                                         
            }
            counter++;
        }

        obj = Detected_Object(left,right,top,bottom);
        objects.push_back(obj);
    }

}
```

Please help me to find out the way to rid of this error.

Thanks.

Comment: what is the error? btw even if you didnt get an error, the pointer you push into the vector is invalid just one line after you push it into the vector. Why do you think you need a vector of pointers instead of a plain vector?

Comment: the way to get rid of this error is to use a debugger ;)

Comment: I can't tell you if this is the issue but you are storing pointers to local objects in your vector.  Those objects go out of scope and leaves your vector full of dangling pointers.  If you really must have a pointer in the vector then you need something like `vector<std::unique_ptr<Detected_Object>> objects;`

Comment: you could try this: `vector<Detected_Object*> objects = vector<Detected_Object*>(); `, you only declared the vector but you did not initialize it.

Comment: @DariusDuesentrieb That won't change anything.  `vector<Detected_Object*> objects;` is the same as `vector<Detected_Object*> objects = vector<Detected_Object*>();`

Comment: @user463035818 i have tried using plain vector instead of vector of pointers but it didn't worked, it also gives segmentation fault. Basically i want to store objects into vector not pointers.

Comment: I have also tried debugging through gdb but it didn't helped.

Comment: I changed the code to use `vector<Detected_Object>` and made cosmetic changes so as to compile it.  It works on my machine; no segmentation fault.  The problem is likely in the code not provided.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `std::vector<Detected_Object>` instead of a `std::vector<Detected_Object*>`, and change `objects.push_back(&obj)` to `objects.push_back(obj)`.

As currently written, the call to `push_back` stores a pointer to a local object, and when that object goes away, the pointer points nowhere sensible.

By storing **objects** instead of pointers you ensure that the objects are still around when the code that creates them finishes.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer, i was doing the same thing before i tried with pointer i.e i had created vector of objects not vector of pointers. But that also gave the same error.

Comment: @S.Vishwakarma -- I can't speculate on what might have been the problem with code I haven't seen; I can only comment on the code that you've shown, and it has a major problem for which I've suggested a fix. If you make that change and still have problems, post new code (probably in a new question).

Answer (score 0):

As previous answers mentioned, push back the object instead of pointer to the object. Also, to debug a segmentation fault you can always use a debugging tool like gdb. Here is a nice tutorial on how to use gdb to debug segmentation faults: http://www.unknownroad.com/rtfm/gdbtut/gdbsegfault.html